# Resize public workspace back to micro

Tags: cloud9-ide

My processes were getting killed, so I resized my free public workspace to small from micro. It turns out it was the RAM limit, not the disk space limit, that was causing the processes to get killed, and I can't afford to upgrade the workspace any higher, so I want to downgrade back to micro, but when I try to, I get an error saying "not enough ram quota". Apparently my RAM usage is at 1.5 GB/1 GB, and if I downgrade to micro it will still be over quota.

How can I downgrade a workspace back to the free, public, micro size? Do I have to delete the workspace and start over?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there are some services that you must be making use of which you need to disable or stop using by killing the process (eg SSH).  At that point, will they allow you to downgrade.

See this blurb at the very end of their FAQ page:
"If you're using premium resources, you can't downgrade your account until you're no longer using those resources."

I am having a different but related issue where my resize to micro is hung and/or taking forever.  The only support channel I can find is to tweet them in hopes they can then DM you for your issue.  I cannot locate a support email.

https://twitter.com/C9Support